# Combining all scenarios in Feature file

Tags: specflow

I have 5-6 small scenarios mentioned in one Feature file.
As we are going ahead with more advanced things, it is needed now to combine all those scenarios and give them scenario outline for different entities.
Please guide me if its a good practice.

Comment: Could you give as a concrete example of your current scenarios

Comment: For Example  you have one web page with 4-5 functions to check which is 4-5 scenarios. In this case is it possible to combine all and make one scenario,

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend making a test for 5 different functions in one scenario. This will be hard to debug and find out why something went wrong. And if another developer/tester has to manage the test results, this will be quite hard to do.

If you realllly want to do it, you might want to take a look at Scenario Outlines with examples.
Take a look at some nice examples at the ToolsQA website. https://www.toolsqa.com/specflow/data-driven-testing-using-examples-keyword-in-specflow/

You can read a keyword from the examples table, which then will trigger a specific flow/function you want to test.
This was quickly thrown together:

```
Scenario Outline: Test 5 different functionalities
Given i am at the Home Page
And Navigate to LogIn Page
When i trigger <function> with variables <var1>, <var2> and <var3>
Then Success message <message>

Examples:
| function       | message                 | var1      | var2        | var3        |
| registration   | Yes this was succesfull | username1 | pw          | pw          |
| forgotpassword | Something went wrong    | email     | notrelevant | notrelevant |

    [When(@"i trigger (.*) with variables (.*), (.*) and (.*)")]
    public void WhenUserEnterAnd(string function, string var1, string var2, string var3)
    {
        switch (function)
        {
        case "registration":
            RegistrationFlow(var1, var2, var3);
            break;
        case "forgotpassword":
            ForgotPasswordFlow(var1)
            break;
        }
    }

  private void ForgotPasswordFlow(string email)
  {
          //do stuff for forgotpassword
  }

  private void RegistrationFlow(string username, string password1, string password2)
  {
          //do stuff for registration
  }
```